# how can I add an argument when I'm calling a c file

Tags: c, linux

Ok, I'm posting my code. I explained things that I want to do before. Posting both my c files, I hope you can find my mistake. Thank you
This is myfork.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int pid;
  int s;
  int waitPid;
  int childPid;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0 && pid != -1) {
    childPid = getpid();
    printf("Child Process ID:%d, Parent ID:%d, Process "
           "Group:%d\n",childPid,getppid(),getgid());
    execl("/bin/cat","cat","-b","-t","-v",argv[1],(char*)NULL);
  } else {
    printf("Original Process ID:%d, Parent Is:%d, Process Group "
           "Is:%d\n",childPid,getppid(),getgid());
    waitPid = waitpid(childPid,&s,0);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

This is test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
  pid_t fork_return;
  fork_return = fork();
  if (fork_return==0) {
    printf("In the CHILD process\n");
  } else {
    printf("In the PARENT process\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried it but it gives something like that:

Original Process ID:0, Parent Is:11875, Process Group Is:12024
Child Process ID:12977, Parent ID:12976, Process Group:12024
and here the code of test.c file

Original ID :0 I think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: And the output must be something like that: First child process information, then the index of test.c file and at the end, parent process information(original process)

Comment: What is that you are trying to `cat`? This program `./myfork <file_name>` is same as running `cat -btv <file_name>`

Comment: @ another.anon.coward - apparently that is what he wants to do.  This is the 3rd question in 3 days on this same thing.  @Ahmet Tanakol - why don't you just post your code and what is wrong and let's just put this baby to bed?

Comment: I have no idea where you posted the things you're trying to do before, and I'm too lazy to look for them. If you're asking us to help you, please take the time to fully explain what you're looking for.

Comment: Using `return 1;` at the end of `main()` usually indicates failure; `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` indicates success.  You should probably print an error message if `execl()` returns - something which always indicates failure (the `exec*()` family of functions never return on success).

Comment: All this to-do about posting your files, and then **they are not there!**

Comment: Well you can find the correct answer guys thats why I actually deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid;
    int s;
    int waitPid;
    int childPid;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Child Process ID:%d, Parent ID:%d, Process Group:%d\n", getpid(), getppid(), getgid());

        execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "-b", "-t", "-v", argv[1], (char*)NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        waitPid = waitpid(pid, &s, 0);

        printf("Original Process ID:%d, Parent (of parent) Is:%d, Process Group Is:%d\n", getpid(), getppid(), getgid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

./myfork test.c

You might want to test that `execl()` doesn't fail, etc. Aside from some very minor errors you basically had it.  The most important thing was to put the parent `printf()` after the `waitpid()`.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to print the information about the parent process after the waiting for child so move `printf` statement after `waitpid`. Also the value of `childPid` in the parent process will be garbage. You should use `pid` instead. Also it is better to handle `-1` separately. Something on these lines maybe:

```
pid = fork();
if ( pid == -1 )
{
   perror("fork");
   /* Handle error*/
}
else if(pid == 0){
  printf("Child Process ID:%d, Parent ID:%d, Process Group:%d\n",getpid(),getppid(),getgid());
  execl("/bin/cat","cat","-b","-t","-v",argv[1],(char*)NULL);
  perror("execl"); /* Print the error message for execl failure*/
}
else{
  waitPid = waitpid(pid,&s,0); /* pid holds child's pid in parent process*/
  printf("Original Process ID:%d, Parent Is:%d, Process Group Is:%d\n",getpid(),getppid(),getgid());
}
```

Side notes:
1. It maybe better to use `pid_t` instead of `int` for `pid` & `waitPid`. You can get rid of `childPid`.
2. You should include `sys/types.h` for `pid_t` & `sys/wait.h` for `waitpid`.
3. Generally when there are no errors `main()` returns `0`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right. Thank you. Both you and Duck are right.